# Decimal/Smallint to Hexadecimal conversion question

Tags: sql-server, casting, type-conversion, hex, decimal

My question has to do with some of the details involved with decimal and hexadecimal conversion as part of a SQL query.

Below is a sample of some of original code:

```
SELECT
    a.COMMUNICATION_PROTOCOL + '_' + CAST(a.ABC_ID1 AS VARCHAR) 
    + '_' + CAST(a.CODE_CNT1 AS VARCHAR) + '_' + CAST(a.ABC_ID2 AS VARCHAR)
    + '_' + CAST(a.CODE_CNT2 AS VARCHAR) + '_' 
    + CASE 
        WHEN a.TEST_1 = 'Completed' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN a.TEST_1 = 'NotCompleted' THEN 'N'
    END 
    + '_'
    + CASE 
        WHEN a.TEST_2 = 'Completed' THEN 'Y'
        WHEN a.TEST_2 = 'NotCompleted' THEN 'N'
    END
FROM
    dbo.All_Tests AS a
```

The code is designed to return a single letter communication protocol identifier, and two-character small-integer identifier, along with whether the tests are supported or not supported. Underscores are inserted between each. So, an example result would be A_14_10_17_40_Y_N.

The problem is that ABC_ID1 and ABC_ID2 are actually hexadecimals, while the others are varchar or small integers. So, in the above example, A_14_10_17_40_Y_N should really read A_E_10_11_40_Y_N, because Decimal (14) = Hexadecimal (0x00000E), and Decimal (17) = Hexadecimal (0x000011). The output code only needs the last two characters in the hexadecimal sequence.

```
SELECT
    ,CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), a.ABC_ID1)
FROM [...]
```

In the test above, The small-integer decimal ABC_ID1 is converted and put out as 0x000E for Decimal (14), and 0x0011 for Decimal (17). I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this the right way, though. IA LEN operator wouldn't help, since the hexadecimal in this case can be either one character (E) or two characters (11), so I'm not sure what the best approach is. Secondly, given the needed decimal to hexadecimal conversion, is it more appropriate to use CONVERT to insert the two-character hexadecimals into the code's character string, or can CAST be used?

Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably create a conversion table myself. Something with a smallint key and a hex string equivalent body. No PK needed, just make sure the index is UNIQUE and use INCLUDE to include the tiny string in the key lookup. Since you only need FF characters at most, the 256 entries should not strain anything, and if you use the table often, it should be small enough that it will be in memory most of the time.

Comment: Would that involve the creation of a new dbo.* table, or is this something that can be done within the SQL query? I ask because table creation is difficult due to non-programming (bureaucratic) reasons.

Comment: The last two digits if a hex is just the last byte... The part you're missing is the fact that hex digits are 0-F (0-9 are the same 0-9 you're used to and A-F is 10-15) This is why 14 = "E" and 17 =  "11" (16+1)... Do a Google or YouTube search for "Convert binary to hex".